# Manifest of a native C++ application?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, manifest

I can't claim that I am an expert in what a .Net Assembly Manifest is, but I think I have a more or less consistent understanding of it. However the fact that when compiling my native C++ application MSVC is `Embedding Manifest...` doesn't fit in my understanding. What do manifests have to do with native C++ applications? Thank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manifests are additional metadata attached to the executable (either embedded into resources, or distributed standalone as .manifest files) — they're used for things like side-by-side assemblies, or UAC compatibility settings. Take a look at [manifest file reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: It is a windows thing. As Cat Plus Plus said: "side-by-side assemblies, or UAC compatibility settings".

Comment: Manifests also affect the new look-and-feel for common controls and dialogs.

Comment: @Ben: Do they? Ah, now it's interesting :)